# Directing to App Store from desktop

Tags: hyperlinks

currently I'm working on a website that offers carpooling service. The user has searched for the desired route and is presened with the list of available drivers:

[image]

When the user has picked out the perfect driver, he should click the green button on the right of his profile picture. After that the user should be presented with information like: in order to use this service, you need to go the App Store / Google Play and download the app + icons to the stores.

I can't figure out how to display this message/directing and can't find examples of how this is usually done. A pop-up window is not a good solution because it might happen that the user has blocked pop-ups. Would it be a good solution if the white box stretches down and shows the message and links below the main information? I appreciate any help from you guys. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Javascript message like this one: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals which is not affected with pop-up blocking.

I believe there will not be such amount of space if you choose to "the white box stretches down and shows the message and links below the main information" since you need to give context to the user why are there 2 icons App Store / Google Play showing up.

Example: On that Javascript message, you can tell the user that in order to call Tommy Cash, he/she needs to download the app from App Store / Google Play. (more marketing lingo/images inserted there, if necessary)

Answer (score 0):

What if you make the green button stretches down and shows the message and links?